# Where did the incorrect spelling 'explaination' come from and where is it still used?

Tags: etymology

The word explanation is often spelt as explaination.

Where did this come from?
Which part of the world commonly uses this?

Comment: @Josh61 I understand that. I meant to ask about its origin. Or is it used everywhere?

Comment: The origin is probably the fact that people think about the verb *expla(i)n* when they write *explanation* and erroneously  they think it is spelled  *expla(i)nation*.

Comment: @Josh61 So there is no specific part of the world where this is common. Everywhere people might make this mistake, right?

Comment: It is just a mispelling of *explanation*.  If it will be  more and more used it may be finally accepted as an alternative spelling...who knows?

Comment: @Josh61 But that tells only about official books right? What about general articles on the internet or even here on ELU?

Comment: I think it is just a common mispelling, with no geographical or other specific context.

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks. Can you add all of your comments in your answer?

Comment: Ironically, the word *misspelling* was misspelled as *mispelling*, it should be **mis**  + **spell**, some would even say that *misspelled* (AmEng) should really be *misspelt* (BrEng).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: Yes, the question should be closed because based on a false premise. See @Josh61's Ngram wrt the claim that the word is "***often*** *spelt as explaination*".

Comment: @Drew Close it if its off-topic but its common. Google "explaination -explanation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Expla(i)nation* is a misspelling of *explanation*, probably due to the fact that it is the noun form of the verb to *explain*.

[Explanation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=explanation):

> - late 14c., *from Latin explanationem*  (nominative explanatio) "an explanation, interpretation," noun of action from *past participle stem of explanare*  "to make plain or clear, explain," literally "make level, flatten," from ex- "out" (see ex-) + planus "flat" (see plane (n.1)).(etymonline)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=explaination%2C%20explanation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexplaination%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplanation%3B%2Cc0): explanation vs explaination.